# Scope when calling a method from another method in the same object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, this

```
var Obj = function(par) {
  this.par = par;
};

Obj.prototype.addPar = function(num) {
  return num + this.par;
};

Obj.prototype.add3more = function(fun, num) {
  return fun(num) + 3;
};

Obj.prototype.callAdd3more = function(num) {
  return this.add3more(this.addPar, num);
};

var obj = new Obj(2);
console.log(obj.callAdd3more(1));
```

I would expect the code above to print out 5, but it prints out NaN. Somehow, addPar seems to get called out of the scope of the object `obj`, because when it gets called `this.par` is undefined.
I cannot understand why or how to correct the code. 
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: An alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/jntzk62x/